# How to always run a template in Azure pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I have a template that has one task only. This template is shared by multiple pipelines that's why it's a template.

The one task inside of it has `condition: always()`. When the pipeline gets cancelled, this task does not run. But if the pipeline fails, it does run. This is how I'm calling the template in the yaml file.

```
      - template: templates\doSomethingInDb.yml
        parameters:
            configs: $(Configs)
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I make it run even if pipeline gets cancelled?

Thank you.

My pipeline yml file.

```
jobs:
    - job:
      displayName: "Build Something"

      timeoutInMinutes: 240

      pool:
          name: myPool

      steps:
          - checkout: self
            fetchDepth: 1

          - task: AzureKeyVault@2
            displayName: "Initialize AzureVault"
            inputs:
                azureSubscription: "Azure Service Connection"
                KeyVaultName: "KV"
                SecretsFilter: "*"

          - task: PowerShell@2
            displayName: "Create directory"
            inputs:
                targetType: "inline"
                pwsh: true
                script: |
                    $null = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path 'C:\Download' -Force

          # Other tasks that belong to the same job.
          # Will cancel the pipeline here for example.

          - template: templates\doSomethingInDb.yml
            parameters:
                configs: $(Configs)
```

Comment: Share your entire pipeline. If it's in a job that hasn't started yet, it won't run even if the condition is `always()`. Your stages and jobs would also need a condition set to override the default condition of `succeeded()`. Refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cstages#pipeline-behavior-when-build-is-canceled).

Comment: I added it. Can you please take a look? It belongs to the same job that gets cancelled.